# Polymorphic this keyword not working as expected inside method body

Tags: typescript

This code works:

```
class Foo {
  axisControl: string = "string";
  directionControl: string = "string";

  filteredAxis: string[] = ["string"];
  filteredDirection: string[] = ["string"];

  test(filteredName: `filtered${string}` & keyof Foo) {
    this[filteredName] = ["otherString"];
  }
}
```

`this[filteredName]` successfully resolves to the `string[]` type. However, it implies that the class references itself with its name. I want to use the [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) instead:

```
class Foo {
  axisControl: string = "string";
  directionControl: string = "string";

  filteredAxis: string[] = ["string"];
  filteredDirection: string[] = ["string"];

  test(filteredName: `filtered${string}` & keyof this) { // polymorphic this
    this[filteredName] = ["otherString"]; // Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'this[`filtered${string}` & keyof this]'.
  }
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't work and the resolved type is `` this[`filtered${string}` & keyof this] `` which doesn't allow me to do anything.

Comment: Weird, but also, why? What is wrong with `keyof Foo`?

Comment: It is not generic enough (would not allow me to `extend` the `class` and add more properties with the `filtered` prefix)

Comment: So maybe I'm missing the exact use case you are describing, but how would `Foo.test` know about the extending classes? It cannot know how it's being used so it will never know the full range of properties available, so you're stuck manually casting the type or finding some way to work with generics (e.g. `<T extends Foo = Foo>(filteredName: keyof T)` maybe?).

Comment: Indeed `Foo.test` will never be aware of the extending classes, but when it is called **from** an extending class, it should be aware of all the matching keys.

Comment: It's not for you? I got IntelliSense for `filteredName` when calling `test` both ways you listed (via the playground).

Comment: Well [that](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1pgB4EsIGF4A7AFwCd4QAuaCcnIgc2gF5oAiOshx9gbnTQAJjjIBTYCRzFCpCtVr0mrDlx79UggGY4QJMeKEBBXBBpqmAbQC6Ky5yW9rAjDr0GxQgCKiJU4uaONnYO3EzszpoY+nQAFG76hgByYAC2YjQABgkeQgAkyBaMAL6Z0ABk0ADWYgCe8FpwiACUaBgYwMR00ABuYNxgAEYgYiokABZ4ljnJaWKRGMWoxUA) works

Comment: But not [that](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1pgB4EsIGF4A7AFwCd4QAuaCcnIgc2gF5oAiOshx9gbnTQAJjjIBTYCRzFCpCtVr0mrDlx79UggGY4QJMeKEBBXBBpqmAbQC6Ky5yW9rAjDr0GxQgCKiJU4uaONnYO3EzszpoY+nQAFG76hgByYAC2YjQABgkeQgAkyBaMAL6Z0ABk0ADWYgCe8FrQJAAWeACUaBgYwMR00ABuYNxgAEYgYioteJY5yWlikRjFqMVAA)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236860/discussion-between-connor-low-and-guerric-p).

Comment: I don't understand: ``this[`filtered${string}` & keyof this]`` is the expected type there; what should it allow you to do?  Please post a [mcve] that shows what you are trying to do and how it fails.  Presumably you need to try to do something inside the implementation of `test()` as well as defining at least one subclass to highlight the relevance of polymorphic `this` instead of `Foo`.  Right now all I see is completely expected and desirable behavior.

Comment: I have posted the full example where it fails

Comment: The problem here is [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WYY73W).  Subclasses of `Foo` can have keys beginning with `filtered` whose types are not `string[]`, and so assigning `this[filteredName] = [""]` could have the effect of assigning a `string[]` value to a property of some completely unrelated type in the subclass.  I'm happy to write this up as the answer, but if there's still something about it that seems wrong to you, could you explain?  Preferably with code?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on wether the method is being called on an instance of the class or an instance of an extending class, the final type which is based on [`this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) can vary, that's why it doesn't resolve in the function body as it doesn't know the execution context yet.

The following code has also a possibility of existing and is totally valid:

```
const test = Foo.prototype.test;

test("filteredAxis");
```

In that case, [`this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) should resolve to `undefined` or `window` (depending on the strict/sloppy mode). There are other cases where `this` could be some object bound with  `Function.prototype.bind`, `Function.prototype.apply` or `Function.prototype.call`.

However, the compiler doesn't throw any error as expected. But there's a possibility to opt into enforcing this by explicitly annotating the method like this:

```
test(this: this, filteredName: `filtered${string}` & keyof Foo)
```

There is an ongoing discussion here about a flag that would enable this behavior by default: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7968

But even with this behavior enabled, the type doesn't resolve inside the function body because of the possible extending classes.

### TL;DR

Inside the method body, the compiler doesn't know the possible extending class from which the method is being called, so [`this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) based types do not resolve. They only do when the compiler knows what's the actual class.

```
class Foo {
  axisControl: string = "string";
  directionControl: string = "string";

  filteredAxis: string[] = ["string"];
  filteredDirection: string[] = ["string"];

  test(filteredName: `filtered${string}` & keyof this) { // polymorphic this
    return this[filteredName]; // Type does not resolve here (unknown current class)
  }
}

const foo = new Foo;
const result = foo.test("filteredAxis"); // But it does here: string[]
```

As a conclusion, [`this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) allows to type the **interface** (parameters and return value) but not the **implementation** of the method.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not the issue.  The compiler should refuse to let you call `test("filteredAxis")`, but there is no `--strictThis` flag as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#7968](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7968).  It is an unrelated limitation of TypeScript, as you can see by noting that adding a line like `this.filteredAxis.map(x => x.toUpperCase());` inside `test()` does not produce a compiler error, but if the compiler is trying to protect you about the possibility where `this instanceof Foo` is false, then it should error there.

Comment: there's a difference between `this` in the function body and `this` in the type declaration. Your example `this.filteredAxis.map(x => x.toUpperCase());` works because it's `this` in the function body, which resolves correctly (not the polymorphic `this`)

Comment: ! But `this` in the function body *is* of type `this`.  Hover over it to get quickinfo from IntelliSense and you'll see `this: this`.

Comment: I got your point, but the general answer is that the execution context is unknown in the method body. `this` could be any of `undefined`, `window` or some subclass. Even some bound object with `Function.prototype.bind`, `Function.prototype.apply` etc...

Comment: If so, then why does changing `keyof this` to `keyof Foo` prevent the error, given that the exact same runtime error can happen in both cases if you call `test("filteredAxis")` like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/Nn4YeW)?  I will grant that (because of the absence of a `--strictThis`) it is technically true that `this` inside of a class method will turn out not to be an instance of the class, but the compiler is absolutely not trying to protect you from that possibility.  It is a completely separate, unrelated issue, and has very very little to do with the question being asked.

Comment: I hope I haven't been too annoying here. I'm not infallible by any means; I've been wrong before about TypeScript and I'll be wrong again in the future.  I might even be wrong now.  But you seem to be quite sure that this issue with calling a class method with a strange `this` context is the answer to your question, and I'd like you to really and truly *consider the possibility that it is not*.  I will disengage from the question now, as it seems highly likely that we are at an impasse, and I wish you luck.

Comment: Thanks, I will also quit as my brain doesn't work anymore. Will probably come back later to refine this answer if needed.